# Unable to npm install or start with electron-quick-start

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using the version of node that is stated on electron's site, which is 7.4.0 and I'm using NPM version 4.0.5 (Windows).

The problem I'm having is with the `npm install` command in the cloned `electron-quick-start` folder. I have tried using the command with `--save-dev`and `-g` but they don't do anything to help.

Upon using just `npm install`;
`fetchMetadeta: still install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree`

With the above stated arguments (output);
`--electron-quick-start@1.0.0`

Then `npm start` after the above output;
[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/03zF0fen)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must get `npm install` to work before you can start the app

You could try the following

- `npm cache clean
  npm install` This will cache clean of npm
- `npm install -g yarn
  yarn install` This will install yarn (This will probably work but it might not be what you're looking for). Yarn is an alternative to npm
- `npm -g install npm
  npm install` This will reinstall npm

And I would look into [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

And if none of those work I would look at 
 [this issuse](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13729) on github

And if that doesn't work I would just look at [google](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&q=fetchMetadeta%3A+still+install+loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree&oq=fetchMetadeta%3A+still+install+loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1.139488.139488.0.140512.1.1.0.0.0.0.107.107.0j1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.1.106.elq39z5wkfE)